# Javascript - get images from a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to load get images and use them in the [js justify plugin](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/Justified.js/demo/) that I am using on my page.
This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var folder = "img/people";

  $.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });

});
var showPhotos = function(photos){

    $('.image-container').empty().justifiedImages({
        images : photos,
        rowHeight: 500,
        maxRowHeight: $('.gallery').height(),
        thumbnailPath: function(photo, width, height){
            var purl = photo.url_s;
            if( photo.url_n && (width > photo.width_s * 1.2 || height > photo.height_s * 1.2) ) purl = photo.url_n;
            if( photo.url_m && (width > photo.width_n * 1.2 || height > photo.height_n * 1.2) ) purl = photo.url_m;
            if( photo.url_z && (width > photo.width_m * 1.2 || height > photo.height_m * 1.2) ) purl = photo.url_z;
            if( photo.url_l && (width > photo.width_z * 1.2 || height > photo.height_z * 1.2) ) purl = photo.url_l;
            return purl;
        },
        getSize: function(photo){
            return {width: photo.width_s, height: photo.height_s};
        },
        margin: 1
    });
}
```

But, when I do console.log(data) I get the this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>listing directory /img/people/</title>
    <style>* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 80px 100px;
  font: 13px "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Arial";
  background: #ECE9E9 -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#ECE9E9));
  background: #ECE9E9 -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ECE9E9);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #555;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #343434;
}
h1 em, h2 em {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
ul li .path {
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul li .line {
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
}
ul li:first-child .path {
  padding-left: 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #303030;
}
#stacktrace {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.directory h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul#files {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul#files li {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 1px;
}
ul#files li a {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#files li a:focus,
ul#files li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
}
ul#files li a.highlight {
  -webkit-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  background: #ffff4f;
  border-color: #E9DC51;
}
#search {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: width ease 0.2s, opacity ease 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: width ease 0.2s, opacity ease 0.4s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
  -moz-border-radius: 32px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-align: left;
  font: 13px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #888;
}
#search:focus {
  width: 120px;
  opacity: 1.0; 
}

/*views*/
#files span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
#files .name {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#files .icon .name {
  text-indent: 28px;
}

/*tiles*/
.view-tiles .name {
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
}
.view-tiles .size,
.view-tiles .date {
  display: none;
}

/*details*/
ul#files.view-details li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}
ul#files.view-details li.header {
  height: 25px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.view-details .header {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.view-details .name {
  width: 60%;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
}
.view-details .size {
  width: 10%;
}
.view-details .date {
  width: 30%;
}
.view-details .size,
.view-details .date {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}

/*mobile*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #search {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-indent: 10px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #search:focus {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .directory h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul#files {
    border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
  }
  ul#files li {
    float: none;
    width: auto !important;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul#files li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
  }
  ul#files li a {
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
  ul#files li a:focus,
  ul#files li a:hover {
    border: 0;
  }
  #files .header,
  #files .size,
  #files .date {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #files .name {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  #files .icon .name {
    text-indent: 41px;
  }
}
</style>
    <script>
      function $(id){
        var el = 'string' == typeof id
          ? document.getElementById(id)
          : id;

        el.on = function(event, fn){
          if ('content loaded' == event) {
            event = window.attachEvent ? "load" : "DOMContentLoaded";
          }
          el.addEventListener
            ? el.addEventListener(event, fn, false)
            : el.attachEvent("on" + event, fn);
        };

        el.all = function(selector){
          return $(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
        };

        el.each = function(fn){
          for (var i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn($(el[i]), i);
          }
        };

        el.getClasses = function(){
          return this.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
        };

        el.addClass = function(name){
          var classes = this.getAttribute('class');
          el.setAttribute('class', classes
            ? classes + ' ' + name
            : name);
        };

        el.removeClass = function(name){
          var classes = this.getClasses().filter(function(curr){
            return curr != name;
          });
          this.setAttribute('class', classes.join(' '));
        };

        return el;
      }

      function search() {
        var str = $('search').value
          , links = $('files').all('a');

        links.each(function(link){
          var text = link.textContent;

          if ('..' == text) return;
          if (str.length && ~text.indexOf(str)) {
            link.addClass('highlight');
          } else {
            link.removeClass('highlight');
          }
        });
      }

      $(window).on('content loaded', function(){
        $('search').on('keyup', search);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="directory">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="/">~</a> / <a href="/img">img</a> / <a href="/img/people">people</a> / </h1>
      <ul id="files" class="view-tiles"><li><a href="/img" class="" title=".."><span class="name">..</span><span class="size"></span><span class="date"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/img/people/1.jpg" class="" title="1.jpg"><span class="name">1.jpg</span><span class="size">57195</span><span class="date">5/19/2017 2:02:18 PM</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/img/people/2.jpg" class="" title="2.jpg"><span class="name">2.jpg</span><span class="size">83345</span><span class="date">5/19/2017 2:02:18 PM</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/img/people/3.jpg" class="" title="3.jpg"><span class="name">3.jpg</span><span class="size">77362</span><span class="date">5/19/2017 2:02:18 PM</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/img/people/4.jpg" class="" title="4.jpg"><span class="name">4.jpg</span><span class="size">71906</span><span class="date">5/19/2017 2:02:18 PM</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/img/people/5.jpg" class="" title="5.jpg"><span class="name">5.jpg</span><span class="size">90691</span><span class="date">5/19/2017 2:02:18 PM</span></a></li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the images from the folder and then use them in this plugin?

Comment: Use input type file and then fetch the required image. after that read the address of image from the input type.

Comment: Could you please provide the code example?

Comment: Yes I'm trying but  instead of full path I'm getting "fakepath/filename". So now stuck with fakepath. Trying to resolve this issues also.

Answer (score 0):

@leff because of browser security framework we cant get location of file.
You will get file path as "C:\fakepath\Capture.PNG". So to resolve that  that fakepath. I found one solution, may be this one work.

So what you can do a simple trick that take a variable and assigned it the base address of you file location. After that append the file name with the base address this will give you file location.

Hope this one solve your problem

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="file" id="imageFile">
      <button id="getFileNameButton">GET-FILE-NAME</button>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $( "#getFileNameButton" ).click(function() {
    var baseAddress = "fixed/file/location";  
    var name = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0].name;  /* get 
          file name*/
    console.log(baseAddress+'/'+name);
  });
 </script>

</html>
```